# i18next interpolation defaultVariables from backend

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next

I have the following i18n setup on my react

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'
import {initReactI18next} from 'react-i18next'
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';

i18n
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(Backend)
    .init({
        backend: {
            loadPath: `test.com`,
        },
        react: {
            useSuspense: false
        },
        whitelist: ['en', 'fr', 'es'],
        fallbackLng: ['en'],
        detection: {
            order: ['cookie', 'navigator'],
            lookupCookie: 'i18nextLng',
            caches: ['cookie'],
            cookieOptions: { path: '/', sameSite: 'strict' },
            checkWhitelist: true
        }
    })

export default i18n
```

I have a unique product with some information as `price` I would like to use as `defaultVariables`

Reading the doc I can change the `inti` config adding

```
{
    interpolation: {
        defaultVariables: {price: 100}
    }
}
```

and then `{{price}}` should be available on all my translations

This part is working great.

But I am getting the product from a server call and I can not find any way to update the `defaultVariables` once `i18n` has been initialized

Answer (score 2):

Officially, the only way to have defaultVariables injected is via init function.
This means you have to load those values before calling init(), and then pass them via init options.

But....

you can try to do this:

```
i18next.services.interpolator.options.interpolation.defaultVariables = { price: 100 }
```

This may work, but this is for sure unsupported and not recommended.

btw: the whitelist option was replaced with supportedLngs: https://www.i18next.com/misc/migration-guide#removed-deprecated

Comment: it is true works! you save my day! for ts you need to do this:

```
const interpolator = i18next.services.interpolator as any;
interpolator.options.interpolation.defaultVariables = { xxx }
```

Comment: I also tried `i18next.services.interpolator.init({interpolation: {defaultVariables: {xxx}}})` to re-init the options, it doesn't work.